# Custom skin for VolumeBar

Tags: css, apache-flex

I want to change the default styling of the volume bar in Flex to [image]

I want to know if it is possible? Any clues would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik VolumeBar only exists in the Spark (Flex 4.x) component set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom skin for your `VolumeBar`.
[About skinning in Flex 4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html).

You can take default skin (`VolumeBarSkin.mxml`) from your sdk, copy code to your custom skin file and change styling there. After that apply your skin to the component (`skinClass` style property).